# Copy serial numbers from string or txt file to Listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a string or a text file which contains some software serial number among other information.

I’m trying to pull out the software serial numbers which all start with `EAN-` and send them to a listbox.

Example of the string or text file:

```
2

EAN-3E4R5-5TGGG-6667Y
Software name Technology
PO #PORD-11111
INV-219149
3
EAN-SXDR5-5DDD-6DDDY
Software name Technology
PO #PORD-11111
INV-219149
```

I'm after just the serial numbers beging with `EAN-`.

So the listbox would be

```
EAN-3E4R5-5TGGG-6667Y
EAN-SXDR5-5DDD-6DDDY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would work:

```
Dim strBuf As String
strBuf = "EAN-3E4R5-5TGGG-6667Y Software nam.............."

Dim Tokens1() As String
Tokens1 = Split(strBuf, "EAN-")
For I = 1 To UBound(Tokens1)

    Dim OneListItem As String = "EAN-" & Split(Tokens1(I), " ")(0)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(OneListItem)

Next
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. All of the other options worked, but this is the option i went with as it worked best for what i needed to do. It working amazingly and without your help i would have been lost. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I read the file with `.ReadAllLines` which returns an array of the lines in the file. I looped through the lines and if a line started with EAN- it was added to the list. Then the list is bound to the ListBox.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lstSerialNums As New List(Of String)
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\Code\Serial Numbers.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        If line.StartsWith("EAN-") Then
            lstSerialNums.Add(line)
        End If
    Next
    ListBox1.DataSource = lstSerialNums
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With a small amount of [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq), you can make quite readable code:

```
Dim srcFile = "C:\temp\SO67550806.txt"
Dim eans = File.ReadLines(srcFile).Where(Function(s) s.StartsWith("EAN-")).ToList()
yourListBoxName.DataSource = eans
```